# how to use custom render(https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/setup/#custom-render) with createroot

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-testing-library, custom-renderer

After upgrading React to version 18 and React testing library to version 13, the error message shown as below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pLf1.png)

I search for custom render (https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/setup/#custom-render) with createroot but in vain.

Comment: Hello and welcome, 
please avoid to add picture to your question, you should copy the error code in your comment. I would suggest you to rad the [how to ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Setting legacyRoot: true but it will be deprecated in React 18
https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/releases/tag/v13.0.0

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).